# Prove or disprove: If $h$ is harmonic on $E$, then $h$ is constant on each $C_i$

Tags: markov-chains, harmonic-functions

> > For a general finite Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ with state space $E$ and transition matrix $P=(p_{x,y})_{x,y\in E}$, not necessarily irreducible, we define the linear space of harmonic functions on $E$ by
> >     $$
> > \mathcal{H}(E)=\mathcal{H}(E,P):=\left\{h\colon E\to\mathbb{R}: h(x)=Ph(x):=\sum_{y\in E}p_{x,y}h(y)~\forall~x\in E\right\}.
> > $$
> >     Assume that the Markov chain has $m\in\mathbb{N}$ essential classes and denote them by $C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_m$.

Prove or disprove the following statements:

**(i)** If h is harmonic, then h is constant on each $C_i$.

**(ii)** For each function $g\colon\left\{1,2,\ldots,m\right\}\to\mathbb{R}$, there exists a unique function $h\in\mathcal{H}(E,P)$ so that $h(x)=g(i)$ for all $i\in \left\{1,2,.\ldots,m\right\}$ and $x\in C_i$.

---

Here is my proof of the first statement:

**(i)** Let $C_i$ be chosen arbitrarily. Consider $P_{|C_i}$, which is a transition matrix and irreducible. Furthermore it is $h\in\mathcal{H}(C_i,P_{|C_i})$. Show that $h$ is constant on $C_i$.

Let $M:=\max\left\{h(x): x\in C_i\right\}$ and choose $x_0\in C_i$ such that $h(x_0)=M$. Such a $x_0$ exists, because $C_i$ is finite. Since $h$ is harmonic, $h(y)\leqslant M$ for all $y\in C_i$ and $\sum_{y\in C_i}p_{x_0,y}=1$ it is
$$
M=h(x_0)=\sum_{y\in C_i}p_{x_0,y}h(y)\leqslant M,
$$
i.e. $h(y)=M$ for every $y\in C_i$ with $p_{x_0,y}>0$.

Now take an arbitrary $y\in C_i$. Since $P_{|C_i}$ is irreducible, there is a sequence
$$
x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n=y
$$
such that $p_{x_i,x_{i+1}}>0$ for all $0\leqslant i\leqslant n-1$. Applying the recent result repeatedly, one gets $h(x_i)=M, 0\leqslant 1\leqslant n$, and therefore $h(y)=M$.

So on $C_i$ it is $h\equiv M$.

---

I think this should be ok?

---

**Edit**

**(ii)** I think I should read the task as $E=\bigcup_{i=1}^m C_i$.

Then my suggestion is the following:

Just set
$$
h(x):=g(i)\text{ if }x\in C_i,
$$
then this function $h$ is harmonic, since for any $x\in E$ there is exactly one $i\in\left\{1,2,\ldots,m\right\}$ with $x\in C_i$ and since $p_{x,y}=0$ for all $y\notin C_i$ it is
$$
h(x)=g(i)=Ph(x)=\sum_{y\in E}p_{x,y}h(y)=\sum_{y\in C_i}p_{x,y}h(y)=g(i)\underbrace{\sum_{y\in C_i}p_{x,y}}_{=1}=g(i).
$$

So it remains only to show the uniqueness.

To do consider a function $f$, being harmonic on $E$ and with the property that
$$
f(x)=g(i)\text{ for all }i\in\left\{1,2,\ldots,m\right\}\text{ and }x\in C_i.~~~(*)
$$
Let $x\in E$ be arbitrary. Then $x\in C_i$ for exactly one $i\in\left\{1,2,\ldots,m\right\}$ and, because of $(*)$ and because $f$ is harmonic, for any $n\geqslant 0$ it is
$$
g(i)=f(x)=P^nf(x)=\sum_{y\in C_i}p_{x,y}^{(n)}f(y).
$$
From this it follows that $f(y)=g(i)$ for all $y\in C_i$ with $p_{x,y}^{(n)}>0$.

Now, because $C_i$ is irreducible, for any $y\in C_i$ there indeed is a $n_y\geqslant 1$ such that $p_{x,y}^{(n_y)}>0$.

So $f(y)=g(i)=h(y)$ for all $y\in C_i$.

So on all $C_i$ the function $f$ is identical with $h$ and so on whole $E$ it is $f=h$.

Am I right with this proof?

Comment: The value at a point $x$ of $E\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^m C_i$ will in generally depend on $x$. Namely, it is $\sum_i P_i g(i)$ where $P_i$ is the probability of reaching essential class $i$ starting from $x$.

Comment: @Raff How did you get that?  I am interested because I tried and tried and did not see howto get it.

Comment: The definition of harmonic function says: the value of $x$ is equal to the expected value after $1$ step starting from $x$. By the Markov property, this is also equal to the expected value after $n$ steps starting from $x$, for any $n$. Let $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Raff Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. As far as I see it is $h(x)=\sum_{y\in E}p_{x,y}h(y)=\sum_{y\in E}\mathbb{P}(X_1=y|X_0=x)h(y)$. Do not see how to continue. I only do see that $\mathbb{P}(X_1=y|X_0=x)=\mathbb{P}(X_n=y|X_{n-1}=x)=\mathbb{P}(X_n=y|X_{n-1}=x,\ldots,X_0=x)$. Maybe you can explain it a bit more detailed (maybe in an answer).

Comment: @Raff Can I expect a more detailed explanation from you? If not, then I should not wait for it.